# How to create a fixed transparent window surrounded by expanding divs?

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to create a fixed position window (a transparent Div?)centered in the browser window that is surrounded by expanding Divs?  This would be to create a window with content scrolling underneath presumably on a lower Z-Index.

SuzyUK came up with an interesting solution on Webmaster World that pushes the surrounding divs off from the fixed center with CSS margin values.

http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/4275625.htm

I found this to suit my needs except for one issue:  I would like to put a header and footer with links within the transparent center div. It seems that it does not want to acknowledge the links in the header and footer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon putting a header at the top of the middle window and a footer at the bottom and placing links inside, I was able to navigate to their destinations without a problem.

**Update:** By adding the `pointer-events` property to both `#header` and `#footer` and setting the value to `auto`, the links become clickable. See the example here: [http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/6pmNQ/](http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/6pmNQ/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Andrew.  I took a look at your link.  The header and footer that I am trying to make should not scroll with the lower z-index content.  They would be header and footer divs placed inside the widow div.

Comment: Aha! Your problem is with one of the CSS properties on `#window`. It has the `pointer-events` property set to `none`. If you delete that property out you're able to interact with the links.

Comment: That's it!  ahhhh.  Unfortunately that makes the content underneath the transparent window inaccessible in Firefox.  The images with links on the scrolling content are no longer accessible.  I guess there is no way to have the header links and for the window to be clicked-through.

Comment: I believe it may be possible... As stated in my edited post, the `pointer-events` can be left as `none` on `#window`, but then it can be added to `#header` and `#footer` and with the value `auto`, and the links on both will then be clickable.

Comment: Andrew, Thanks for pointing out the pointer events property.  The solution I came up with sets the #window  pointer-events property  to none and the #header and #footer pointer-events property to auto. http://jsfiddle.net/vngogh1/qa68R/14/

Comment: ha. looks like we came up with the same.  Thanks Andrew.